# What is real periodic function

Tags: functions, definition

I would like to know what is real periodic function.

I understand what is periodic function, but I do not understand what is "real" periodic function.

Comment: A function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is periodic.

Comment: So the function, which operats in real numbers. Thanks

Comment: it's a periodic function with body image insecurities :p